# "TypeError: len() of unsized object" when using insert for arrays

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror

objective: to insert a row in the array at a given index position (i)

Language used: python with numpy library

example:

```
i=2.0;
a=array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]],dtype=float);
a=insert(a,i,[-1,-1,-1],axis=0);
```

this gave the error: `TypeError: len() of unsized object`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us what language you're using?  That's frequently done by editing the question to include the language as one of the tags (where "typeerror" now is).  Also, if there's more than one commonly used implementation, you might want to tell us which one you're using.

Comment: I have found the solution, but stack overflow won't let me post it until 8 more hours.. "i=int(2.0)"

Comment: `2` makes a lot more sense than `int(2.0)`, and you don't need those semicolons in Python.

Answer (score 6):

If you check the documentation for `insert`:

```
>>> help(insert)
```

you find:

```
Parameters
----------
arr : array_like
    Input array.
obj : int, slice or sequence of ints
    Object that defines the index or indices before which `values` is
    inserted.
values : array_like
    Values to insert into `arr`. If the type of `values` is different
    from that of `arr`, `values` is converted to the type of `arr`.
axis : int, optional
    Axis along which to insert `values`.  If `axis` is None then `arr`
    is flattened first.
```

Looking at what you've done, it is evident that the problem is that `obj` must be an int, slice, or a sequence of ints, not a floating point (`i = 2.0`).

Your example will not throw an error if you set `i=2`. I don't know whether that is what you want, because you didn't state the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

This is to note that numpy version 1.8.1 does implicit casting to int and hence doesn't raise that error for OP's code!

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__version__
1.8.1
```

OP's code -

```
>>> i = 2.0;
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]],dtype=float);
>>> a = np.insert(a,i,[-1,-1,-1],axis=0);


>>> a 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  4.],
       [-1., -1., -1.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 6.,  7.,  8.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the bug.
It was giving the error i=2.0 is a index and also float which confused python

solution is to typecast the index attribute of the insert() as int

that is as per the example of the question:

CODE:

```
i=int(2.0);     # TYPE CASTED AS INT

a=array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]],dtype=float);

a=insert(a,i,[-1,-1,-1],axis=0);
```